# Upload success but no file in server

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have want to upload the picture from user to the server. The response tell me the upload was success but there is no file in my server.

Here is html

```
<button class="btn-group" ngf-select ng-model="userData.picFile" name="picFile" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Select</button>
```

And this is my Controller

```
var profilePic = "profile_"+localStorageFactory.get('userdata').username;

/////////////////////////////upload//////////////////////////////////////////
$scope.submit = function() {
  if ($scope.userData.picFile) {
    $scope.upload($scope.userData.picFile);
  }
};

// upload on file select or drop
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://pettention.ga/pettention/img/profile',
        data: {file: file,
                name: profilePic}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

I have call upload function when submit form. And this is Response Message

```
Success IMG_0067.JPGuploaded. Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
```

Sorry for my bad in English. Thank you.

Comment: it seems to be a server application problem. Could you share your server code to receive the upload?

Comment: Sorry. The server side is my friend jobs. It is may be the server permission right ??

Comment: Maybe... that url https://pettention.ga/pettention/img/profile that receives the post may be your problem. There a lot of issues to receive upload from web server, permission, size of upload, http method post other things. My suggestion is to check the server log error. I can't see any problem with your angualr code above...

Comment: I have change permission to 777 and test the size from 1- 10 Mb. but all not work. Where can I check my log ??

Comment: i checked your server https://pettention.ga/pettention/img/profile and it's is a linux server so i don't know where is. I work with windows server only, sorry :(

Comment: That's a server issue so need to be fixed on the server side.